# Libre Office form -- need data sheet layout with a lookup field

Tags: libreoffice, forms, libreoffice-base

I am trying to develop a timecard form.  The fields are ID, task, date, start time, and stop time.  I want to create the form as a datasheet.  I don't know the specific name for this, but I want it to look like a typical spreadsheet.

The thing I'm stuck on this that I would like the "task" field to be something like a combo box that can look up values from another table.  Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detailed instructions with an example file are at https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/143186/how-to-use-user-selected-value-from-combobox1-in-combobox2-select-statement/?answer=143231#post-id-143231.

Many of the changes are made by right-clicking on the column header of the table control.

[image: edit column]

Comment: I appreciate it, truly, but those instructions are completely beyond me.  And it looks like they are trying to do something more complicated than what I am trying to do.  From your picture, I was able to convert the column to a list box.  But now the list box comes up empty.  I can't figure out how to convince it to find its values in the "task" table.  I've clicked every control and field that I think could possibly be relevant.  I've worked with list boxes several times, but this seems to be different.  Any ideas what I should do next?  Thanks again!

Comment: Cancel the alert!  Wasn't as different as I thought.  Figured it out from previous examples.  But I got the conversion to a list box from your pic.  Thanks for that!